# Control user actions with jQuery

Tags: jquery, session

I want to write javascript that will kill sestion on the web page if user did not make any action for some time taken from configuration. 
How can I know that user did not make any actions by using jQuery.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you want to do this on client side? Your server-side language should already be well equipped with a mechanism to invalidate sessions.

Comment: Set the cookie timeout when the session is created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could trap the mousedown and keydown events for the entire document, and then setup a timeout to run if the events are not raised within a certain timeframe:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _idleEventId = null;
        var _idleMaxMilliSeconds = 10000;

        function OnIdle() {
            alert('You\'re idle!');
        }

        $(document).bind("mousedown keydown", function() {
            clearTimeout(_idleEventId);
            _idleEventId = setTimeout(OnIdle, _idleMaxMilliSeconds);
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            _idleEventId = setTimeout(OnIdle, _idleMaxMilliSeconds);
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello World
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but what with all other events like mouse move, mouse click or any other user activity?

Comment: just add them as a bind parameter: bind("mousedown keydown mousemove etc"), find the entire list at http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Answer (score 2):

how to use cookie just in case: http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp

then i would have like this

**NOTE:** just a proof of concept not tested!

```
setInterval("checkForActivity()", 5000); //set a reasonable time..

function checkForActivity() {
    var user_has_moved_at = (new Date()).getTime(); //generate a time
    var time_elapsed = getCookie( COOKIE_NAME ); //get a time from previous stored
    //check how many time is passed from last move
    if ( ( user_has_moved_at - time_elapsed ) < 3600 ) { 
     //less then 1 hour.. user is still here..
        $(document.body).bind('mousemove',
        function() {
         // so update the fresh air...
            setCookie( COOKIE_NAME , user_has_moved_at);
         // unbind event
            $(document.body).unbind('mousemove');
        });

    } else {
     // more then 1 hour... destroy cookie... user is out
        setCookie(COOKIE_NAME, null); //destroy cookie
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

To check, that a user didn't do anything, you could watch for events that signify user interaction:

```
var last_seen = 0;
var timeout = null;
$('body').mousemove(function () {
  last_seen = (new Date()).getTime();
  window.clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = window.setTimeout(clear_da_session, 10000);
});
/* ...  and likewise for things like
   $('input').focus();
   $('a').click();
   and 'keypress' events
*/
```

The `clearTimeout` and `setTimeout` stuff takes care of something (i.e. the `clear_da_session` function) happening after some time of not firing any of the listed events.

However, I want to re-emphasize my comment from above: Don't do this at home, kids! Use whatever your serverside language has on board. This is by far more reliable than trying to track something, that might be untrackable.

Comment: i think is better to check for body mousemove just at some interval of time not everytime! ;-)

Comment: @aSeptik: How would you do this? If you check, e.g., at second 5 to 6 for mouse moves, but the user moves it in seconds 6 to 10, then you fire the wrong behaviour at second 10. And, yes, it *is* a performance nightmare, but hey, who am I to question the OP's reasons.

Comment: hey bro i'm with you at 100%, i have only saied to try to reduce the nightmare for fun! ;-)